# Uniqueness of a Latent Representation Under Monotonicity Condition?

Tags: uniform-distribution, copula, latent-variable, identifiability

Suppose that I observe a bi-variate joint distribution over two random variables, $(X_1,X_2)$. I want to represent this joint distribution as arising from a  function $F$ applied to i.i.d. uniform random variables, that is, I want to find $F:\mathbb [0,1]^2\to\mathbb R^2$ such that when $U_1,U_2$ are i.i.d. $Uniform(0,1)$ random variables, we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}X_1\\ X_2\end{pmatrix} = F(U_1,U_2)$$
I also know that $F$ satisfies the following monotonicity property: if $F_2(U_1,U_2) = F_2(U_1',U_2')$, and $U_1 > U_1'$, then $X_1 > X_1'$ and vice versa, if $F_1(U_1,U_2) = F_1(U_1',U_2')$ and $U_2 > U_2'$, then $X_2 > X_2'$. Do these conditions suffice to ensure uniqueness of $F$? If not, what further conditions might I need? Is there any keyword I can search for to find a literature discussing questions like this one?